# IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: usermanager_userprofile.email_address

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-2.2

I'm developing a registration app that use User model with OneToOneField.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=150)
    gender = models.CharField('Gender', max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('Date of birth', null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField('Profile image', upload_to='users_upload/profiles/%Y/%m/%d')
    company_name = models.CharField('Company Name', max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    fiscal_data = models.CharField('Fiscal data', max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField('Address', max_length=200)
    postcode = models.CharField('Zip Code', max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=75)
    telephone_number = models.CharField('Telephone', max_length=20)
    email_address = models.EmailField('Email')

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['fiscal_data', 'email_address']


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, password_validation
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import UserProfile

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'name', 'surname', 'gender', 'date_of_birth',
            'user_type', 'profile_image', 'company_name',
            'address', 'postcode', 'city', 'country',
            'telephone_number', 'email_address',
            'fiscal_data',
            ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import UserProfileForm
from .models import UserProfile

@transaction.atomic
def createUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.userprofile) 
            profile_form.full_clean()  
            profile_form.save()  
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'usermanager/editing/create_user.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**create_user.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}

  <div class="card-body">
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-md-auto">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow" value="Create Profile">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

When I try to register a new user using the form I see this error message:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: usermanager_userprofile.email_address

This happen even if I try to register a new user using the administration panel.

How I can resolve this?

I've used [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) strategy to create my model, for for createUser view I've used [this](https://gist.github.com/vitorfs/cbe877156ba538a20c53c9a1cea29277#file-views-py).

**Traceback**:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-user/
>
> Django Version: 2.2.5 Python Version: 3.6.8 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'kernel', 
>   'usermanager'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
>     52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/app_usermanager/usermanager/views.py"
>   in createUser
>     30.             profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form
>
> File
>   "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in save
>     453.                     'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /create-user/ Exception Value: The
>   UserProfile could not be changed because the data didn't validate.

Comment: This means there is already such `UserProfile` with that `email_address`.

Comment: This is impossible bacause I'm trying to add the first user

Comment: @MassimilianoMoraco: likely there is somehow already data in the database. Perhaps due to some triggers, other views? Can you inspect the db?

Comment: I've deleted the DB before follow the indication of @ruddra , then the DB is total empty. Also before write this question I've do same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UserProfile` model, there is a field:

```
email_address = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
```

When you add [**`unique=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#unique) it means that field will be unique for all the entries in that model. You can either remove that keyword argument and run makemigrations and migrate. Or you need to enter unique email address for each `UserProfile` entry.

---

#### Update:

Probably the error is occurring because you are not validating the profile form when you initiated it second time:

```
profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.userprofile) 
profile_form.full_clean()  
# before calling save, you need to call profile_form.is_valid()
profile_form.save()
```

TBH, I think you should remove your post save signal `create_user_profile` and `save_user_profile`, because it is over complicating your implementation of `createUser` method. Also, post save signals would be useful if you didn't have a mechanism to create a `UserProfile` but you have a form to do that, so why need a signal?

If you remove those signals, then try the following code:

```
def createUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
         
            profile_form = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile_form.user = user
            profile_form.save()
```

FYI, you should use `snake_case` when naming methods as per pep8 standard. So its better if you name `createUser` to `create_user`.

Comment: I've followed your indication and now I've the same error but for `fiscal_data`: `UNIQUE constraint failed: usermanager_userprofile.fiscal_data`. However I need that `email_address` and `fiscal_data` must be unique..

Comment: Please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: I've updated my question with your indications. Now I've this error message: `The UserProfile could not be changed because the data didn't validate.` I think that the real problem is inside 'createUser' views

Comment: Thank you, now it work fine! For me is the first time that create a registration system and a complex create view

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to prevent a string to be the same even if it had different caps.

Example dog and Dog shouldn't work.

**Code example**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = CICharField(max_length=255, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This category has already been registered."})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.name = self.name.lower()
        self.name = capitalizeFirtChar(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

this code above gave me the error, and I solved it by adding this if statement to the save function

**Before**

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.name = self.name.lower()
    self.name = capitalizeFirtChar(self.name)
    super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

**After**

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.name = self.name.lower()
    self.name = capitalizeFirtChar(self.name)

    # If the name already exists
    if not Category.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists():
         super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```